# What does the "Permission denied" error for apt-get mean?

Tags: ubuntu

```
apt-get autoclean 
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

What does this mean ?

Comment: It means that you don't have permission to manipulate the apt download lock. Are you root? :-)

Comment: no , i'm new to ubuntu i have no idea how it works ^^' . do you know how i can fix this ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get autoclean`, and when prompted for a password, use your _own_ password (not the root password.)

Comment: i tried it same issue

Comment: Unlikely to be the same issue. Please [edit] your question to show us exactly what you typed, and exactly what the system responded. Don't use a screenshot, but instead copy'n'paste (or copy-type).

Comment: As root, it could  mean the /var partition is full.

Answer (score 1):

This mean : there is an instance of the package manager running. To avoid any conflict a lock file will be created to ensure the execution of an only one instance of `apt`. Generally this problem may reproduce during the execution of the `apt-daily` autoupdate service.

Try:

```
sudo pkill apt
sudo pkill dpkg
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt autoclean
```

*Answerd after reading comments: the same issue with `sudo`.*